# Ghost image on D'n'D from canvas 2d into canvas 3d

Tags: java, image, swing, drag-and-drop, awt

I'm trying to create an ghost image while performing an `awt.dnd` operation from a canvas 2D which is in a panel on top of the program into a canvas 3D which is also in a panel in the middle of the program. The D-n-D stuff is implemented and working, with `setDragImage()`.  I can easily get my ghost image, but I need to get it working for Java 1.6, where this method is missing.

Now I tried a lot with glass panels etc :

- Glass panel is working except over the Canvas3D (heavyweight component)
- If I use a AWT glass panel (Frame) it paints my ghost image but the whole program black

[GHOST drag and drop, over multiple windows](http://free-the-pixel.blogspot.com.au/2010/04/ghost-drag-and-drop-over-multiple.html):
saw this interesting link to create a `JDialog`, also created it but I don't know how to get my dialog non opaque: `WindowsUtils.setOpaque(d, false);` is no class I have and I can't find it. It is necessary because Ii need this 1 pixel space on my cursor to get focus on my canvas3d. I hope anyone has any suggestions I cant find anything useful for my problem on Google anymore, thanks

Comment: alright sorry! its about java-dnd-ghostimages!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're in for a lot of work.  I'm not farmiluar with `canvas3d` or `canvas2d`, but as you say, they seem to heavy weight components, these tend not to support transparency.

Per-Pixel Alphering was introduced into Java 6.10 as a private API and has begin made public with Java 7.

You can access the private APIs, but it is not recommended, the next question you need to ask, is what to do when the API's don't exist?!

```
public static void setOpaque(Window window, boolean opaque) {
    try {
        Class<?> awtUtilsClass = Class.forName("com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities");
        if (awtUtilsClass != null) {
            Method method = awtUtilsClass.getMethod("setWindowOpaque", Window.class, boolean.class);
            method.invoke(null, window, opaque);
        }
    } catch (Exception exp) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that tip im gonna try this, any chanche of solution is nice, i need that dragn drop image. i even tried to search in the dnd transferable class how they implement the setDragImage() method but i cant find the part where its actually drawn.

Comment: First, don't forget to make the "drag" window undecortated, otherwise Java won't be able to make it opaque. Secondly, the transfer API is nutritious for not providing an implementation capable of supplying a drag image (or ignoring it). Thirdly check out [DragSource#createDragSourceContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/dnd/DragSource.html#createDragSourceContext%28java.awt.dnd.peer.DragSourceContextPeer,%20java.awt.dnd.DragGestureEvent,%20java.awt.Cursor,%20java.awt.Image,%20java.awt.Point,%20java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable,%20java.awt.dnd.DragSourceListener%29)

Comment: ps - Don't forget, support the drag image is going to be platform specific

Comment: yeah thanks a lot the non opaque style already works. sorry i didnt got i what u meant with "the next question you need to ask, is what to do when the API's don't exist?!" when can they not exist ?

Comment: `AWTUtilities` was introduced in Java 6 update 10 as a private API.  If users of your program are using an earlier version Java then this, the API won't exist (I've not tested this on Java 7 as it has it's own API so it may not exist there either)

Comment: i will add a picture now what it looks like with setDragImage() which is pretty good. http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/829/dndghostimage.jpg/ now i want this also for java 1.6 and the ghostimage centered on the mouse position + allowing me my rollover on the canvas3d ( the green thing ). but i think if its not worth the work, so maybe i ll just create a JDialog next to my mouse  with the image drawn into, so i have definitly access to the canvas3d rollover and it should work on every plattform.

Comment: its not worth the fancyness if the compatibilities are even worse, thank you a lot for your time and your suggestion, also learned something :D